# CSS sprites image not showing properly with text

Tags: html, css, sprite

I am using following CSS to show up images through CSS image sprites as a background images. Images comes up according to file extension but href/link text not coming up in line and dividing into two lines.

```css
a[href$='.pdf'] { 
padding-left: 68px;
background: transparent url(/images/icons.png)  no-repeat;
 display: inline-block; /* Display icon as inline block */
    width: 44px; /* Icon width */
    height: 48px; /* Icon height */
    background-position: 0 -100px; /* Icon background position in  */
}
```

anyone please help

Comment: a demo with your issue? Just seeing this css, we can't fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
a[href$='.pdf']{
    display:inline-block;    
}
```

and use ::before selectors to generate an icon in front of the href

```
a[href$='.pdf']::before{
content: ''; /* content property must be added */
background: transparent url(/images/icons.png)  no-repeat;
 display: inline-block; /* Display icon as inline block */
    width: 44px; /* Icon width */
    height: 48px; /* Icon height */
    background-position: 0 -100px; /* Icon background position in  */
    margin-right:50px; /* use margin instead of padding */
}
```

An example can be found here: [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/mk98j5mq/1/)